# Clear function on Canvas isnt working properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

When you click the Clear Canvas button on codepen, it will appear as if the canvas is cleared but if you try drawing again, all the old lines will re-appear.

```
//Redraw
function redraw(){
    $("#clearcanvas").click(function () {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 
    });
    context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {      
      context.beginPath();
      if(clickDrag[i] && i){
        context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
      }
      else {
        context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
      }
      context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();
  }   
}
```

Full code: http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/AXGKvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are storing the information for each drawn line inside a arrays being `clickX`, `clickY`, and `clickDrag`. The canvas will draw each of those lines over even after you clear the canvas. What you will want to do is empty those array items:

```
$("#clearcanvas").click(function () {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 
   clickX = []; clickY = []; clickDrag = []; // or 'new Array()' or '.length = 0'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The old lines are re-appearing because they're stored in `clickX` and in `clientY`, and when you basically draw in the canvas you call `redraw` method in your code, which draw everything in these objects. You're missing to clear both of these objects.

(I've forgot one, `clickDrag`.)

To clear a array (such object) without losing its references, just set its `'length'` property to `0`.

```
clientX.length =
clientY.length =
clickDrag.length = 0
```